# Check exact characters in custom labels using contains keyword

Tags: apex

I have a custom label ('hcv') which has values `ICT;Thérapie;`

I have a Text field in Vf page in which user enters a value and save it. Before saving, i need to check if the entered value is same as in label. else, it should show warning message.

If i use snippet,`System.label.hcv.contains('test')`  it works fine and shows error.

but for `System.label.hcv.contains('CT') // not ICT as in label` it returns true (should return false for my case) because of 'contains'.

Is there a way to check for exact value.? my clients dont wanna use picklist value for this.

Comment: Your "answer" should have been a comment (I may never have seen it if not for the fact this window was still open), but using Set/contains works, but it's inflexible. I find that the "extra" effort of using a regular expression almost always pays off in the long run. Use whichever you'd like, but keep in mind that the Set method is far less powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a Pattern (by which, of course, I'm referring to a "regular expression"). First, change your label to be a regular expression:

```
(ICT|Thérapie)
```

Where `()` simply creates a "group", and `|` means "OR" (as you might expect). You can use as many OR values as you'd like in a row.

Then use the [Pattern and Matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm) classes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Label.hct);
Matcher m = p.matcher('test');
if(!m.matches()) { // The text does not match
    // show an error
}
```